# multiprocessing.pool.map_async does not run my function

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run a pool of identical processes on a number of cores simultaneously. This is a simplified version of my code. 
It seems like my function is never called by `map_async`, plus, the code gets stuck (right after `print (4)`).
Any idea?

```
import multiprocessing
pairs =  [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f'],['g','h']]

def printPairs(first, second):
    print('pairs =', pairs)

def parallel(function, pairs):
    cpu_no = multiprocessing.cpu_count()   
    if len(pairs) < cpu_no:
        cpu_no = len(pairs)

    p = multiprocessing.Pool(cpu_no) 
    p.map_async(function, pairs, chunksize=1)
    print('3, p = ', p)
    p.close()
    print('4')
    p.join()
    print('5')    
    return

parallel(printPairs, pairs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `pairs` an argument of `printPairs`:

```
import multiprocessing


def printPairs(pairs):
    print('pairs =', pairs)

def parallel(function, pairs):
    cpu_no = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    if len(pairs) < cpu_no:
        cpu_no = len(pairs)

    p = multiprocessing.Pool(cpu_no)
    p.map_async(function, pairs, chunksize=1)
    print('3, p = ', p)
    p.close()
    print('4')
    p.join()
    print('5')
    return

pairs =  [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f'],['g','h']]
parallel(printPairs, pairs)
```

and it works.

Output:

```
3, p =  <multiprocessing.pool.Pool object at 0x10169d0f0>
4
pairs = ['c', 'd']
pairs = ['a', 'b']
pairs = ['e', 'f']
pairs = ['g', 'h']
5
```

Comment: I`ve tried that one too.  This is really odd as it still does not run in my computer. It gets stuck exactly at the same point.

Comment: What Python version and what os?

Comment: Python 3.5.1 (using Anaconda 4.0.0) on a Windows 10.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. `map` or `starmap` works, but `_async` variant does not

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that on Windows you need to get the function results even if you don't need them. It seems like a good idea even if it isn't necessary.

```
import multiprocessing
pairs = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f'],['g','h']]

def printPairs(pair):
    print('pair =', pair)

def parallel(function, pairs):
    cpu_no = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    if len(pairs) < cpu_no:
        cpu_no = len(pairs)

    p = multiprocessing.Pool(cpu_no)
    res = p.map_async(function, pairs, chunksize=1)
    print('3, p = ', p)
    print(res.get())
    print('4')
    p.close()
    print('5')
    p.join()
    print('6')
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parallel(printPairs, pairs)
```